# How can I write this map function in the pre ES6 format?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have this map function I found in a tutorial, and I'm interested as to how I'd write this in the old way - i.e writing the word "function" rather than the "=>" arrow format.

```
const example = spaceships.map((spaceship) => ({
    homePlanet: spaceship.homePlanet,
    color: spaceship.color
}));
```

I assumed that I could write it like this, but I get an error when adding the extra brackets.

```
const example = spaceships.map(function(spaceship) ({
    homePlanet: spaceship.homePlanet,
    color: spaceship.color
}));
```

Comment: Sharing the error message is useful to everyone. In this case, seems like a debug question and syntax error: function syntax is `function() {}` and there's an extra set of round parenthesis in your second example: `function() ({})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `return`

```js
const example = spaceships.map(function (spaceship) {
  return {
    homePlanet: spaceship.homePlanet,
    color: spaceship.color
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The arrow function return when the `{}` is not provides so this syntax
`() => ({foo: "bar"})` will return the object `{foo: "bar"}` but when you use a function you need to explicitly return the object

```
const example = spaceships.map(function(spaceship){
    return {
           homePlanet: spaceship.homePlanet,
           color: spaceship.color
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your function in old format:

```
const example = spaceships.map(function(spaceship) {
  return {
     homePlanet: spaceship.homePlanet,
     color: spaceship.color
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const example = spaceships.map(function(spaceship){
    return {
        homePlanet: spaceship.homePlanet,
        color: spaceship.color
    }
});
```